# Could not resolve view with name '/hello/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Tags: grails, servletexception

I am not able to open the controller on grails project

I am using the following versions of groovy and grails

C:\Users\Two95Admin>grails -version
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this releas| Grails Version: 3.1.10
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_74
C:\Users\Two95Admin>

I have successfully created the helloworld project using following commands

grails create-app helloworld
cd helllworld
grails
create-controller hello
run-app

My project is executed on localhost:8080 
[Screenshot of an Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhuri.png)

Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /hello/index
Class
    javax.servlet.ServletException
Message
    Could not resolve view with name '/hello/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Trace

```
Line | Method
```

->> 1229 | render                in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

---

|   1029 | processDispatchResult in     ''
|    973 | doDispatch . . . . .  in     ''
|    895 | doService             in     ''
|    967 | processRequest . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    858 | doGet                 in     ''

Please help me solving the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `grails-app/views/hello/index.gsp` does not exist.  You will need to create that file.

Comment: index.jsp file is located there. but still it is not working

Comment: Try creating an 'index.gsp' file (gsp, not jsp), whose contents are simply   <h1>Should be simple</h1>.  I just created an app using 3.1.10 and generated the controller as you did, then created an index.gsp file as suggested by JSB. Worked fine displaying that message at the url of "http://localhost:8080/hello/index".

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I have to create jsp file should be inside the view/hello folder

Comment: @SMANSARI "Actually I have to create jsp file should be inside the view/hello folder" - Correct.  That is the path I described in the answer above.  I used `grails-app/views/hello/index.gsp` but `grails-app/views/hello/index.jsp` would work as well.  I used GSP in the example because the question didn't indicate that you were are using JSP and GSP is by far more common in a Grails app.

Comment: You said `view/hello` but that should be `views/hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing hello page you should generate views. "grails generate-views hello" try this way. I think adding jsp file is not the correct way.